# Nginx can't read some files while can read others

Tags: nginx

I made a fresh instalation of nginx to serve my `laravel`applicaton. 
Some files show while others doesn't show. When I load the page it says:

[image: 403 forbidden files]

I have read online that this usually is a permission problem so I have tried:

1. chown -R :www-data /path/to/webroot
2. chmod -R 755 /path/to/webroot

Which we can see on the image bellow:

[image: permissions set]

My nginx deamon is running as `www-data` from the `nginx.conf` file:
`user www-data;`

I have tried every solution that I could find online and none seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`sites-available conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/x/public/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;


    #error logs
    error_log /var/log/nginx/x.com-error.log error;

    server_name x.com www.x.com;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

`nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
   worker_connections 8096;
   multi_accept on;
   use epoll;
}
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;
http {
   ##
   # Basic Settings
   ##
   sendfile on;
   tcp_nopush on;
   tcp_nodelay on;
   keepalive_timeout 15;
   types_hash_max_size 2048;
   # server_tokens off;
   server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
   # server_name_in_redirect off;
   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   default_type application/octet-stream;
   client_max_body_size 50M;
   ##
   # SSL Settings
   ##
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ##
   # Logging Settings
   ##
   access_log on;
   error_log on;
   ##
   # Gzip Settings
   ##
   gzip  on;
   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_min_length 10240;
   gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
   ##
   # Virtual Host Configs
   ##
   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: The nginx configuration would be helpful.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have updated the question to include the conf

Comment: There is nothing obvously wrong in there ... anything in the nginx log files when you do these requests?

Comment: Did you look at your logfiles? This is the first step to debug problems.

Comment: Permissions should not be set blindly (and files do not need the execute bit, and I always recommend for files **not** to be owned by the web server process user). Connect (su) as `www-data` and try to go to  `/usr/share/nginx/x/public/` does that work? Do you have `am/fonts/etc...` as subdirectories there?

Comment: Please post both your errors and the result of `ls` as text in your post, not as inlined images, thanks.